# Is Cross-Posting Allowed?

Tags: discussion

[In a business where staff churn is costly, should I let employees lead and request their salary increase?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/74434/in-a-business-where-staff-churn-is-costly-should-i-let-employees-lead-and-reque)

Is a cross-posted question.

It's interesting, perhaps on-topic, but it is specifically cross-posted. Is that okay?

Comment: I tend to vote down _all_ the cross-posts when asker isn't [forthright  about this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141824/165773) - because this is netiquette norm that long precedes Stack Exchange (and will likely be there long after SE is gone). In this case though this seems to be not the case - to me that means cross posting is not an issue here

Comment: Seemed like a legit question to pose here, theory was way out there with the space cadets, but many questions are.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pure cross-posting has been identified as being counter to StackExchange's spirit [in this meta thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu). So the answer to the title question is a flat **no.** As Lumberjack pointed out, [this answer in particular](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/243797/260382) does a stellar job of describing *why* cross-posting is a problem on SE

Now, if a question was about a central topic and OP is asking about the impact on a workplace here and the general value of the practice from a macro-economic perspective, then I'd argue that that's not pure cross-posting but a case of two very different questions about the same topic. **The typical test is whether answers on one site could just as easily have been posted on another site.** In that case you're dealing with a cross-post and those are not allowed by community consensus.

That said, the question you've linked here arguably isn't that great of an example since I doubt it's on-topic on Economics and the version here is unclear and convoluted.

Comment: [This answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/243797/256587) in particular details why it is a bad idea to cross post.

Comment: @Lumberjack Good catch, that one's kind of buried in there but it gives a good overview.

Comment: Cause it might be weird:" if we didn't discourage cross posting (even when the question is very much on topic in both places), we would see duplicate questions featured on the front page, which would look a bit weird." But seemingly neither is closed.

Answer (score 8):

A question like that seems to have one foot in two SE sites, it's both an economics and a workplace question.  The economics are being examined in the economics SE, but it also has workplace ramifications, so it is not merely a theoretical question suited for only economics.

Usually cross posting is frowned on severely, but I think this particular question is a rare exception.

Comment: I agree with this. Questions that are cross-posted at Workplace and Academia, or Mathematics and Statistics, are going to get pretty much the same answer at both sites. This particular question will get an economic theory answer at Economics and a people management answer here at the Workplace.

Comment: I also agree with this but that's because I asked the question! :) You'll notice that I queried the etiquette of it in the cross post. That's got to win me an award for being meta-meta-meta, right?

Comment: I'd argue that it's not an exception, it's just not a real cross-post.

Answer (score 6):

If people want to ask good, interesting, researched, quality questions that they posted elsewhere, I have absolutely no problems with it being posted here.

Questions like the one you linked are unfortunately an overwhelming minority of "plz help me" cross posted questions.