# Close a question as it's a cross post?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/review/close/55228) came up in the close review and looking at the reason given it seems a bit odd:

> Other: Cross post [serverfault.com/questions/837491/trusting-the-new-sysadmin](https://serverfault.com/questions/837491/trusting-the-new-sysadmin)

So, yes it came from another stack exchange, however I know sometimes migrating questions between stack exchanges can be a bit of a difficult task. Can we migrate the question from server fault? If so, should we?

To be honest, I feel the question needs closing on serverfault and leaving open here. It would be ideal if we could migrate it. What are people's thoughts?

I'm aware of [this meta question](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3877/is-cross-posting-allowed) which talks about how cross posting shouldn't generally be allowed, but I'm more curious on the allowing if the other question is suspected to be closed off as it should be here.

Comment: I think the crossposting was unnecessary. He had what appears to be 2 different questions and should have put one in each place. SF isn't concerned about the ramifications from a workplace and we aren't concerned about the technical aspects. Were it to happen again, I'd just suggest 2 separate questions addressing the disparate issues.  That said, it's got 2 close votes and whether it'll actually get closed is questionable. Even so, I personally find the question to be  a good one (as edited) and will vote to reopen it, should that happen.

Comment: @ChristopherEstep I was with you until you mentioned that it's a good question. How is "*Does anyone have any experience working in such an environment? Should I get worried about my future here?*" answerable in any meaningful way?

Comment: I was the first to comment on the cross posting and would not have VTC but the person argued rather than revise so I VTC.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes, cross-posting is a sufficient reason by itself to close a question.** In the rare case that a question is on-topic on two sites in the same form, the mere fact that the cross-post will split answers should in my view be reason enough to close it. But as I mentioned [in my answer](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3880/25739) on the related question this will hardly ever come up because sites typically have a narrow focus and relatively little overlap. Workplace is about interpersonal issues and professionalism, Project Management is about, well, project management. Programmers deals with general Software Development topics while Security focuses on a specific IT domain.

So can one situation lead to multiple questions on multiple sites? Sure. This would have been one example. I can think of on-topic, well-written questions around it that would be appropriate on both this site and Security. In such a case I wouldn't call it cross-posting though the OP *should* link to the other site with something like "*A question on the security implications of admin accounts has been asked on Security.se*".

**It just so happens that this isn't a good question on either site.** When your only question is "*What is your experience?*" that's about as clear as sign you can get that the question is not suitable for StackExchange. I've cast the final close vote for that reason.

Answer (score 3):

**I think this is a worthwhile question and should be reopened.**

As it was initially posted, the two questions were identical. Since then both questions have been put on hold and the Workplace question has been edited significantly to focus more on the workplace issues. Cross-posting is discouraged here, but in my opinion the question is a better fit for the Workplace than at Server Fault, so our version should stay. I think there is a possibility that the question would be valid for both sites, one looking at professional solutions and the other looking at technical solutions, as [this Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu/75012#75012) explains, though SF views the technology question as off-topic for them.

This post was lacking a clear addressable question, so I added the line

> How can I get my boss to trust me with the tools I need to do my job?

I think this, along with all of the previous edits, brings the question back on-topic and it should be reopened.